# Draw circle on arc

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have the following code

```
float angle = (-1) * 360 * progress / max;
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, angle, false, foregroundPaint);
        double dotX = Math.cos(startAngle+angle) * rectF.centerX() + rectF.width()/2.0;
        double dotY = Math.sin(startAngle+angle) * rectF.centerY() + rectF.height()/2.0;
        canvas.drawCircle((float)dotX, (float)dotY,strokeWidth*1.5f, dotPaint);
```

This is intended to draw an arc and a red circle at the end of the orc. however my circle is not on the arc depending on the "progress" value, ie the angle.
For example on 40 it is on arc, on 47 it is outside  ..etc

What is it  I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote a question

Answer (score -1):

if I understanding your question true, just use a library for creating arc layout and then at the end of it add your circle.

arc layout:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4823